# How to access au sub array in bigquery standard SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

in Bigquery standard SQL, I try to select only rows where "tags.value.name" = "start unopen capsule journey" is true

But I dont know how I can access to this stuff.

When I try something like that, it doesn't work :

```
SELECT my_table.fl_coins_life_time_balance
FROM my_table
WHERE "start unopen capsule journey" IN UNNEST(my_table.tags.value)
```

This one doesn't work also

```
SELECT my_table.fl_coins_life_time_balance
FROM my_table
WHERE "start unopen capsule journey" IN UNNEST(my_table.tags)
```

[You can check my Table structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUJ4Z.png)

I'm sorry for this question who is maybe a noob question, but thx a lot for your help, I'm a little but stuck here ^^

Answer (score 0):

It depends if and where there are arrays inside of your structure. If there are no arrays use this:

```
With data as (
    select struct(struct( "unopen" as name, 8888 as id) as value) tags , 555 fl_coins union all
    select struct(struct( "start unopem capsule journey" as name, 8847 as id) as value) tags , 111 fl_coins union all
    select struct(struct( "unopen" as name, 8888 as id) as value) tags , 222 fl_coins 
    )

SELECT
*
FROM 
    data
where tags.value.name="start unopem capsule journey"
```

If there is an array use this:

```
With data as (
    select struct([struct( "unopen" as name, 8888 as id)] as value) tags , 555 fl_coins union all
    select struct([struct( "start unopem capsule journey" as name, 8847 as id)] as value) tags , 111 fl_coins union all
    select struct([struct( "unopen" as name, 8888 as id)] as value) tags , 222 fl_coins 
    )

SELECT
*,tag_
FROM 
    data, unnest(data.tags.value) as tag_
where tag_.name="start unopem capsule journey"
```